# How to use input fields as controlled components nested under forms present in ant design library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I have an ant design `Form` with `Input` as a `FormItem`. I simply want to capitalize and trim all the text entered in the input, so I want it as a controlled component. Since it is not directly manipulate value with `value` field for a component wrapped inside `getFieldDecorator`, so I attached onChange event with `setFieldsValue` prop passed by the component as suggested by the warning. But upon calling `setFieldsValue` for every `onChange` event, the changed value doesn't seem to reflecting on the input.

Could someone please suggest the correct way of doing it? Thanks. I'm attaching a minimal version of my code, stripping out unnecessary functions

```
class AddProduct extends Component {
  handleCodeChange = e => {
    const finalCode = e.target.value.toUpperCase().trim()
    console.log(finalCode)
    this.props.form.setFieldsValue({ code: finalCode })
  }

  render() {
    const {
      getFieldDecorator,
      getFieldsError,
      getFieldError,
      isFieldTouched,
    } = this.props.form
    const FormItem = Form.Item
    const codeError = isFieldTouched('code') && getFieldError('code')

    return (
      <div>

        <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <FormItem
            label="Code"
            validateStatus={codeError ? 'error' : ''}
            help={codeError || ''}
          >
            {getFieldDecorator('code', {
              rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please input product code!' }],
            })(
              <Input onChange={this.handleCodeChange} />
              )}
          </FormItem>
        </Form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Form.create()(AddProduct)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ant Design's `Form` component and `getFieldDecorator` don't seem intended to be controlled.

Their example of using `onFieldsChange` and `mapPropsToFields` is probably the closest thing to being controlled.

https://ant.design/components/form/#components-form-demo-global-state

```
import { Form, Input } from 'antd';

const FormItem = Form.Item;

const CustomizedForm = Form.create({
  onFieldsChange(props, changedFields) {
    props.onChange(changedFields);
  },
  mapPropsToFields(props) {
    return {
      username: Form.createFormField({
        ...props.username,
        value: props.username.value,
      }),
    };
  },
  onValuesChange(_, values) {
    console.log(values);
  },
})((props) => {
  const { getFieldDecorator } = props.form;
  return (
    <Form layout="inline">
      <FormItem label="Username">
        {getFieldDecorator('username', {
          rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Username is required!' }],
        })(<Input />)}
      </FormItem>
    </Form>
  );
});

class Demo extends React.Component {
  state = {
    fields: {
      username: {
        value: 'benjycui',
      },
    },
  };

  handleFormChange = (changedFields) => {
    this.setState(({ fields }) => ({
      fields: { ...fields, ...changedFields },
    }));
  }

  render() {
    const fields = this.state.fields;
    return (
      <div>
        <CustomizedForm {...fields} onChange={this.handleFormChange} />
        <pre className="language-bash">
          {JSON.stringify(fields, null, 2)}
        </pre>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Demo />, mountNode);
```

Comment: Can you specify How we can use onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} with this method.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution allows you to use input fields as controlled components nested under forms present in the Ant Design library:

```
{
    getFieldDecorator("code", {
        getValueFromEvent: e => e.target.value.toUpperCase().trim(),
        rules: [{ required: true, message: "Please input product code!" }]
    })(<Input />);
}
```

Comment: Hi, code-only answers are not encouraged because in most cases they do not provide sufficient context to understand and evaluate the proposed solution. I suggest you to edit your answer and provide a description in plain language.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and this is my solution:

```
const NodeEditor = ({ data, onChange }) => {
  const [form] = Form.useForm();

  // Update data reactively
  useEffect(() => {
    form.setFieldsValue({
      ...data,
      label: data.label.toUpperCase().trim()
    });
  }, [data, form]);

  return (
    <Form form={form} layout="vertical" initialValues={data}>
      <Form.Item name="label" label="Подпись">
        <Input placeholder="Подпись для элемента" />
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  );
};

export default NodeEditor;
```

Happy coding!

Answer (score -2):

try setTimeout
`setTimeout(() => {
    this.props.form.setFieldsValue({ code: finalCode });
}, 40)`

Comment: Hey @Ayush were you able to solve this? I'm kinda having a similar problem